# WPF KeyBinding in listview

Tags: wpf, listview, key-bindings

I have this code :

```
<Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Content Version:" Style="{DynamicResource WorkspaceLabelsStyle}" />
    <ListView Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" x:Name="VersionsList" Margin="0,5,5,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedObject , Mode=TwoWay}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItemVersionLinkNode}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Width="360" Grid.RowSpan="4" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True">
        <ListView.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Gesture="Delete" Command="{Binding Path = DeleteSelectedVersionsCommand }"></KeyBinding>
                </ListView.InputBindings>
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
                        <MenuItem Header="Open Linked Version" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenLinkedVersionInAnotherWorkspaceCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete all" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteAllVersionsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete selected" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteSelectedVersionsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Background="WhiteSmoke" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="SubItemVersionLinkNode" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Icon" Width="120">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"  Width="32" Height="18" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>                  
                        <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Content Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ContentName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Version Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>       
                    <Style TargetType="{x:TypeListViewItem}">                                        
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                        <Setter Property="local:CMListViewLinkedVersionsItemBehavior.IsListViewLinkedVersionsItemBehavior" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="mvvm:EventToCommand.Event" Value="MouseDoubleClick" />
                        <Setter Property="mvvm:EventToCommand.Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=VersionsList, Path=DataContext.OpenLinkedVersionInAnotherWorkspaceCommand}" />
                        <Setter Property="mvvm:EventToCommand.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding OpenLinkedVersionInAnotherWorkspaceCommand}" />

                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />                                        
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>                 
            </ListView>
```

the important lines are:

```
<ListView.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Gesture="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedVersionsCommand}">      </KeyBinding>
</ListView.InputBindings>
```

It makes me a list with items I want to bind the command on delete key press.
It's working but only when the window is selected but when one of the elements is selected it's not working.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: By "one of the elements", do you mean one of the ListViewItems?

Comment: yes , one of the elements = one of the ListViewItems

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a minimal example mimicking yours.  Have you tried setting a tracepoint in your command's CanExecute callback to make sure the key binding isn't working, as opposed to your command simply being disabled?  Also, try commenting out other bits which could be interfering, like your `ListViewItem` style and the drag & drop properties.  Do you have any other custom styles/templates applied to `ListView` or its items?

Comment: yea you right , when i remove the style it's working. :). how can i get it work without removing the style ?

Comment: I'd try commenting out all of the setters in your style and verify that it still works.  Then, try adding them back one by one to see which one is interfering, then figure out why.

Comment: Thank you, found the problem in one of the setters